# How to auto scroll to top for material2 angular2 dialog box?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using https://material.angular.io, specifically the Dialog box (https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview). My problem is when I position the dialog box using

```
config = {'width':'200px', 'height':'400px', position: {'top':'150px', 'left':'400px'}}
```

I notice that when I click a button to show the dialog box, it scrolls all the way down... is there some way to make it so that when I click the button to show the dialog box, that it stays at the top/scrolls to top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in the style.css file.

```
.md-dialog-container { height: 100vh !important; top: 0 !important; position: fixed !important; }
```

**Another way:-**

You can adjust the position of dialog component using updatePosition() method of MdDialogRef. Use this code in your dialog component:-

```
import { MdDialog, MdDialogConfig, MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

constructor(public dialModalRef: MdDialogRef<any>) { }

changePosition() {
  this.dialModalRef.updatePosition({ top: '50px', left: '50px' });
}
```

Read more about it here:- https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog

Hope so it's work fine.

Comment: So your solution is to just create the div in one place (by default) but shift after it is created? Does that create a visible effect to the user that it shifted?

Comment: @Harleen Kaur Arona i tried your solution but it moved the entire dialogue box which is not what i want.what i want is just to scroll the matDialog to the top